# Ubuntu preseed - disable i386/multiarch

Tags: 12.04, preseed, multiarch

I'm installing servers with pre-seeding but our local mirror only has amd64 packages. Yet, installer tries to fetch sources for i386 packages as well and basically strolls on it for a while during installation.

I have googled around, read through the preseed docs, but it seems there's no way to tell it to disable multiarch already during installation. Am I blind, or is it really not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never...

Finally found this, somehow:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785165

Tested this preseed option (in Ubuntu 18.04), and it works. It seems specifying a single value for multiarch effectively restricts its default behavior of adding i386 package support.

Add this to your preseed file:

```
d-i apt-setup/multiarch string amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about preseeding, but I suppose that configuring `sources.list` is possible. If so, you could use something like that:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://mirror...
```

See also: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Comment: Thanks, I'll check today whether that can be used in pre-seeding as well. Point being, for additional repos it probably can be, but there's a separate `mirror` section in `d-i` configuration, that later creates the `sources.list` automatically.

Comment: So far no luck with preseeding :( If anyone has any more ideas I'd appreciate. Otherwise i'll just have to mirror i386 repo as well :(

Comment: Just an idea: Create an empty i386 repo. That way your servers are happy to fetch i386 package information but you don't have to waste disk space.